# Why using auto with reference to an array gets deduced to a pointer?

Tags: c++

```cpp
#include <iostream>

int main(){
  int ar[] = {1,2,3};
  int (&ref)[3] = ar;

  auto ar_ref1 = ref;
  int (&ar_ref2)[3] = ref;

  printf("%d\n", sizeof(ar_ref1)); // 8
  printf("%d\n", sizeof(ar_ref2)); // 12
  return 0;
}
```

I was expecting `ar_ref1` to be initialized the same as `ar_ref2`  but it's not. It became `int*`, why is that? The compiler can clearly see `ref` is a reference to an array with 3 ints.

Comment: TL;DR of the dupes: `auto` never deduces a reference type.

Comment: Because `ref` is a reference (alias) to `arr`, `auto ar_ref1 = ref;` is the same as `auto ar_ref1 = arr;`

Comment: `auto` never deduces references or `const` or `volatile`.  If you want those deduced, use `decltype(auto)`.